# RoR Static pages Help page should have the title 'Help'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I am working through Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial, and I am doing the Chapter 5 exercises. Can someone please explain why this test is failing?

My routes.rb

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  root 'static_pages#home'
  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help',    via: 'get'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get
end
```

My static_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

  let(:base_title) { "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App" }

  describe "Home page" do

    it "should have the h1 'Sample App'" do
      visit root_path
      expect(page).to have_content('Sample App')
    end

    it "should have the base title" do
      visit root_path
      expect(page).to have_title("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App")
    end

    it "should not have a custom page title" do
      visit root_path
      expect(page).not_to have_title('| Home')
    end
  end

  describe "Help page" do

    it "should have the h1 'Help'" do
      visit help_path
      expect(page).to have_content('Help')
    end

    it "should have the title 'Help'" do
      visit help_path
      expect(page).to have_title("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Help")
    end
  end

  describe "About page" do

    it "should have the h1 'About Us'" do
      visit about_path
      expect(page).to have_content('About Us')
    end

    it "should have the title 'About Us'" do
      visit about_path
      expect(page).to have_title("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About Us")
    end
  end

  describe "Contact page" do

    it "should have the content 'Contact'" do
      visit contact_path
      expect(page).to have_content('Contact')
    end

    it "should have the title 'Contact'" do
      visit contact_path
      expect(page).to have_title("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Contact")
    end
  end
end
```

My test:
    gvyntyk@gvyntyk-r60:~/rails_projects/sample_app$ rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
    ....F...F

```
Failures:

  1) Static pages Help page should have the title 'Help'
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_title("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Help")
       expected #has_title?("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Help") to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:34:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Static pages About page should have the title 'About Us'
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_title("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About Us")
       expected #has_title?("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About Us") to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:47:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.67805 seconds
9 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:32 # Static pages Help page should have the title 'Help'
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:45 # Static pages About page should have the title 'About Us'
```

Though web-application works, I can open /about and /help pages.

```
gvyntyk@gvyntyk-r60:~/rails_projects/sample_app$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.2 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2015-01-25 20:01:19] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-01-25 20:01:20] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2014-11-13) [i686-linux]
[2015-01-25 20:01:20] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=17314 port=3000


Started GET "/assets/custom.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-25 20:01:29 +0200


Started GET "/assets/rails.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-25 20:01:31 +0200


Started GET "/help" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-25 20:01:42 +0200
Processing by StaticPagesController#help as HTML
  Rendered static_pages/help.html.erb within layouts/application (2.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 516ms (Views: 513.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-25 20:01:43 +0200


Started GET "/assets/custom.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-25 20:01:43 +0200


Started GET "/assets/static_pages.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-25 20:01:43 +0200


Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-25 20:01:43 +0200


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-25 20:01:43 +0200


Started GET "/assets/static_pages.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-25 20:01:43 +0200


Started GET "/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-25 20:01:43 +0200


Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-25 20:01:43 +0200


Started GET "/about" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-25 20:01:51 +0200
Processing by StaticPagesController#about as HTML
  Rendered static_pages/about.html.erb within layouts/application (0.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (2.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 56ms (Views: 55.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-25 20:01:51 +0200


Started GET "/assets/custom.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-25 20:01:51 +0200


Started GET "/assets/static_pages.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-25 20:01:51 +0200


Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-25 20:01:51 +0200


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-25 20:01:51 +0200


Started GET "/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-25 20:01:51 +0200


Started GET "/assets/static_pages.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-25 20:01:51 +0200


Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-25 20:01:51 +0200
^C[2015-01-25 20:02:34] INFO  going to shutdown ...
[2015-01-25 20:02:34] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
Exiting
```

Comment: Without view code we can not see if you are really visiting this page. Try too look at server console to see if there is 302 error

Comment: I don't get 302 error, I added log server and I can open /about and /help pages. But I'm not sure it works correctly and passes test afterwards.

Comment: Could this be because your title isn't actually being set in the view?

Comment: Yes... I didn't add <% provide(:title, 'Help') %> and <% provide(:title, 'About us') %> in appropriate files. Thanks, guys.

Comment: Cool, I answered the question properly below.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your test is fine, so your test is probably failing because the title actually isn't getting set properly.

I guess you just need to add something like this to your view:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Title') %>
```

or makes sure the title you're sending is the same as the title you're testing for.

Comment: BTW... Why we need to use falling test? I can't understand it now. Just check out that test works altogether?

Comment: When using TDD (Test Driven Development) we write failing tests (red) before making them pass (green) because then we have a little more confidence that we're testing the right thing. If we see the test fail in a way we expect, we can be fairly sure our test is working. You don't have to test first (TDD) but it's generally considered best practice in the Ruby community. Hartl has an aside on when to test: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#aside-when_to_test

Comment: I hope that answered your question. Let me know if I misunderstood what you were asking?

Comment: Also, I noticed you're new here. If you think this answer was helpful you can mark it as the accepted answer. Find out more about accepting answers on StackOverflow: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: Thanks, Benjamin, I understood about falling test. At least I think so :). I think that practice will help me to understand more and better.